# Does dependency inversion really work?

Tags: oop, dependency-inversion

I have read about Dependency Inversion (the 'D' in SOLID) and looked at a few examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

However, I can't see how the dependency can be totally gotten rid of!

According to the article the relation Consumer --> Utility can be changed to Utility --> Consumer by introducing a contract/interface in the consumer package.

Further more, the reversed dependency can be fully decoupled by moving the contract/interface to a separate package like Consumer --> Contracts <-- Utility.

Now, with the above layout; for Consumer to use the Utility shouldn't there be a factory? Which then brings back the original dependency as follows:

Consumer --> Factory --> Utility

Comment: Yes It works! For further information, read about [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and this [article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) from Martin Fowler.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I'll describe a place where Dependency Inversion Principle came about where I work.

I do work with a Content Management system - a system that stores images and lets people retrieve them.

Well, here's what our current (bad) C++ code looks like:

```
Retrieve()
    // code to initialize a vendor's API
    // code to pass in system credentials
    // code to clear the vendor's "current workitem list"
    // code to pull the document to the current workitem list
    // code to get content files from that document
    // code to format those files for passing back to the user
```

Basically, hooks into the vendor left and right.  And this is just one function - it's the same throughout the code.

Now, imagine you're told:

"Sumith, we're moving to a new Imaging system - we're moving from Vendor ABC to Vendor XYZ.  Start working on changing the code to work with the new system."

... uh... um.... yeah... you're going to have to redo *all that code*.  In every single function, in every part of your program that interfaces with that vendor.  The Dependency Inversion joke basically goes, "You wouldn't sodder your lamp directly into the electrical wiring, would you?" Well, our group has.

Now, here's how Dependency Inversion handles that.

```
Retrieve()
    // Code that initializes an Interface we coded up
    // Code that uses that interface, to pull up a doc (which, again, is an interface)
    // Code that returns that doc interface's data
```

... and that interface?

```
Interface SimpleExample
    void Initialize();
    DocExample GetDoc();
Interface DocExample
    byte[] GetFileData();
```

So, when the manager says, "Hey, we're moving to Vendor XYZ..."

... all you need to think to yourself is, "Okay, I need to program a new class that implements my 'SimpleExample' interface, and then I can plug it right into my existing code without having to change any of that program's code!"

Right now, I'm working on rewriting the whole thing, and let me tell you, Dependency Inversion Principle is already saving me boatloads of time.  I write a "ContentManagement" interface (well, I'm using an abstract class, but it functions similarly) - and all I have to do, is program a class that implements the ContentManagement interface.  Then I can have code like this:

```
ContentManagement vendorToUse;
if (some criteria or such)
    vendorToUse = instanceOfNewVendor;
else
    vendorToUse = instanceOfOldVendor;
vendor.Initialize();
Document doc = vendor.Retrieve(...);
... etc
```

... trying to do that *without* D.I. would be a nightmare - you'd basically have to have two separate versions of the function.

Comment: Thanks for answering Kevin. Am I correct in calling what you did with your project, decoupling? I do that quite often (Resharper -> Extract Interface). Similar to how a ceiling rose will be used for a lamp than solder it into the circuit. But what I don't get is how is the dependency inverted such that, your project doesn't have to reference the vendor's libraries directly or indirectly (via a factory which your project references which in turn references the vendor libs).